# C++ UUID stored as integer

Tags: c++, linux, uuid

Is it possible to convert an UUID into a 128 bit integer using c++ under linux . Once I convert UUID to integer, I need to convert the 16 byte integer into a byte array so that I can send it to another server via TCP.

As far as I know(correct me if I am wrong), there's no out of the box support for dealing with 16 byte integers in C++, can you please shed some light on how to do this? If it's not possible to store and send it as an integer, I am thinking about sending the uuid as string.

Comment: why not just use [`boost.uuid`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/uuid/)?

Comment: 1) In what form do you originally hold the UUID? 2) What operations do you want to perform on the 128-bit integer?

Comment: I hold it as a string, but I realized that I generate string from uuid_t which is basically unsigned char[16], so I guess I don't need to do anything to convert it, I am wondering if those 16 bytes would be  compatible with .Net's GUID though.

Comment: @erin : Then maybe you should post _that_ as a question.

Comment: I'd rather give it a try first, thanks for the suggestion:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to represent it as a 128 bit integer?

How is the UUID represented? Presumably it's a string or already some 16-byte type. If it's a string then you can compute the 16-byte array representation yourself, and if it's already some 16-byte long type then you can just view it directly as a 16-byte array.

As always, whatever you do you'll have to be sure all parties agree on byte ordering for the network representation.

---

C++ implementations aren't required to have a 128 bit integer type, but one of the built in types may be 128 bits. `long long` perhaps. Or your implementation might provide an extended integer type you can use.

Clang and I think GCC both support a type __uint128_t, but unfortunately do not follow the C++ requirements for extended integers for this type. However 128 bit arithmetic should work and so you should be able to do the normal things to stick a UUID into this type and then view it as a 16-byte array.

Comment: thanks guys, I found what I needed, uuid.h is able to generate UUID of type uuid_t which is unsigned char array of size [16]. I don't need to convert it to anything. I am wondering if those 16 bytes would be compatible with .Net's GUID type.

Answer (score 0):

For implementing 16 byte integers in C++ you can check out:
http://straymindcough.blogspot.com/2012/01/on-int128t.html

As for: "Is it possible to convert an UUID into a 128 bit integer using c++ under linux". Answer is Yes.

Kind regards,
Bo